# Calling Express Route internally from inside NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, express, routes

I have an ExpressJS routing for my API and I want to call it from within NodeJS

```
var api = require('./routes/api')
app.use('/api', api);
```

and inside my **./routes/api.js** file

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
router.use('/update', require('./update'));  
module.exports = router;
```

so if I want to call `/api/update/something/:withParam` from my front end its all find, but I need to call this from within another aspect of my NodeJS script without having to redefine the whole function again in 2nd location

I have tried using the HTTP module from inside but I just get a "ECONNREFUSED" error

```
http.get('/api/update/something/:withParam', function(res) {
   console.log("Got response: " + res.statusCode);
   res.resume();
}).on('error', function(e) {
  console.log("Got error: " + e.message);
});
```

I understand the idea behind Express is to create routes, but how do I internally call them

Comment: why would you hit the server like that? Why won't you rather just do the same operation there only?

Comment: because I don't want to repeat a function twice

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The 'usual' or 'correct' way to handle this would be to have the function you want to call broken out by itself, detached from any route definitions. Perhaps in its own module, but not necessarily. Then just call it wherever you need it. Like so:

```
function updateSomething(thing) {
    return myDb.save(thing);
}

// elsewhere:
router.put('/api/update/something/:withParam', function(req, res) {
    updateSomething(req.params.withParam)
    .then(function() { res.send(200, 'ok'); });
});

// another place:
function someOtherFunction() {
    // other code...
    updateSomething(...);
    // ..
}
```

Comment: Ya, after doing some more digging, I kinda realized this was probably the only way to go about it. I wasn't sure if Express had a built in "call your own route" type of function going for it. Thanks

Comment: If you do not need to call subsequent middleware, this will do the trick

Answer (score 11):

This is an easy way to do an internal redirect in **Express 4**:

The function that magic can do is: **app._router.handle()**

**Testing:** We make a request to **home** *"/"* and redirect it to **otherPath** *"/other/path"*

```
var app = express()

function otherPath(req, res, next) {
  return res.send('ok')
}

function home(req, res, next) {
  req.url = '/other/path'
  /* Uncomment the next line if you want to change the method */
  // req.method = 'POST'
  return app._router.handle(req, res, next)
}

app.get('/other/path', otherPath)
app.get('/', home)
```

Comment: I get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'handle' of undefined`

Comment: Note that setting `req.url` as in `req.url = '/other/path'` will remove any querystring parameters: if you want to preserve them, possibly best to parse and reform the url in some (safe) way.

Answer (score 3):

I've made a dedicated middleware for this : [`uest`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uest).

Available within `req` it allows you to `req.uest` another route (from a given route).

It forwards original cookies to subsequent requests, and keeps `req.session` in sync across requests, for ex:

```
app.post('/login', async (req, res, next) => {
  const {username, password} = req.body

  const {body: session} = await req.uest({
    method: 'POST',
    url: '/api/sessions',
    body: {username, password}
  }).catch(next)

  console.log(`Welcome back ${session.user.firstname}!`

  res.redirect('/profile')
})
```

It supports Promise, await and error-first callback.

See the [README](https://github.com/abernier/uest#readme) for more details

Comment: Hope it doesn't terminate request-response cycle?

Answer (score 0):

Separate your app and server files with the app being imported into the server file.

In the place you want to call your app internally, you can import you app as well as 'request' from 'supertest'. Then you can write

```
request(app).post('/someroute').send({
  id: 'ecf8d501-5abe-46a9-984e-e081ac925def',
  etc....
});`
```

Answer (score 0):

This is another way.

```js
const app = require('express')()
const axios = require('axios')
const log = console.log

const PORT = 3000
const URL = 'http://localhost:' + PORT
const apiPath = (path) => URL + path

app.get('/a', (req, res) => {
    res.json('yoy')
})

app.get('/b', async (req, res) => {
    let a = await axios.get(apiPath('/a'))
    res.json(a.data)
})

app.listen(PORT)
```