# Approach for changing fields in documents that are related to other documents

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am building an API and came across an issue that I have a few ideas of how to solve, but I was wondering what is the most optimal one. The issue is the following:

I have a `Product` model which has, for the sake of simplicity one field called `totalValue`.

I have another model called `InventoryItems`, which, whenever is updated, the `totalValue` of `Product` must also be updated.

For example, if the current `totalValue` of a product is say `$1000`, when someone purchases 10 screws at a cost of `$1` each, a new `InventoryItem` record will be created:

```
InventoryItem: {
  costPerItem: 1,
  quantity: 10,
  relatedToProduct: "ProductXYZ"
}
```

At the same time of creation of that item, `totalValue` of the respective `ProductXYZ` must be updated to now `$1100`.

The question is what is the most efficient and user-friendly way to do this?

Two ways come to my mind (and keep in mind that the code bellow is kinda pseudo, I have intentionally omitted parts of it, that are irrelevant for the problem at hand):

1. When the new `InventoryItem` is created, it also queries the database for the product and updates it, so both things happen in the same function that creates the inventory item:

   ```
   function async createInventoryItem(req, res) {
     const item = { ...req.body };

     const newInventoryItem = await new InventoryItem({...item}).save();

     const foundProduct = await Product.find({ name: item.relatedtoProduct }).exec();

     foundProduct.totalValue = foundProduct.totalValue + item.costPerItem * item.quantity;

     foundProduct.save();

     res.json({ newInventoryItem, newTotalOfProduct: foundProduct.totalValue });
   }
   ```

That would work, my problem with that is that I will no longer have "a single source of truth" as that approach will make it hard to update the code, as updating a given `Product` will be scattered all over the project.

2. The second approach that comes to my mind is that, when I receive the request to create the item, I do create the item, and then I make an internal request to the other endpoint that handles product updates, something like:

   ```
   function async createInventoryItem(req, res) {
     const item = { ...req.body };  

     const newInventoryItem = await new InventoryItem({...item}).save();

     const totalCostOfNewInventoryItem = item.costPerItem * item.quantity;

     // THIS is the part that I don't know how to do
     const putResponse = putrequest("/api/product/update", { 
       product: item.relatedtoProduct, 
       addToTotalValue: totalCostOfNewInventoryItem 
     });

     res.json({ newInventoryItem, newTotalOfProduct: putResponse.totalValue });
   }
   ```

This second approach solves the problem of the first approach, but I don't know how to implement it, and it is I'm guessing a form of requests chaining or rerouting? Also I am guessing that the second approach will not have a performance penalty, since node will be sending requests to itself, so no time lost in accessing servers across the world or whatever)

I am pretty sure that the second approach is the one that I have to take (or is there another way that I am currently not aware of??? I am open to any suggestions, I am aiming for performance), but I am unsure of exactly how to implement it.

Comment: Found the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38946943/calling-express-route-internally-from-inside-nodejs