# How do I call an api from another api nodejs?

Tags: node.js

```
app.put('/sounds',(req,res)=>{
      var animal = req.body.animal;
      //from this api call I want to call 
      //app.get('/:animalname',(req,res)=>{res.render('animal.ejs')})
      })
```

I have already defined the `app.get('/:animalname')` above this api call.

How do I do that? Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calling Express Route internally from inside NodeJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38946943/calling-express-route-internally-from-inside-nodejs)

Answer (score 0):

res.redirect('/endpoint') helps you redirect your request. You can read about it here: [Link](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html)